# DataList records not appearing horizontally

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DataList on my webpage, which I am populating through a data srouce at runtime.
Though I have set `RepeatDirection=Horizontal` and `RepeatColumn=5`, I am still not getting the columns to be repeated in the horizontal direction. Thye are getting stacked over each other vertically.

I have the following the layout for my data list:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" 
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal">

<ItemTemplate>
<tr></tr><tr style="text-align:center"><td ><strong><%#Eval("QuotedVersions")%></strong></td></tr><tr></tr>
<tr><td><strong>URL No.</strong></td>   <td><strong>URLs.</strong></td>   <td><strong>Avg.RJ Value</strong></td></tr>
<tr>    <td style="width:40px">URL1</td>    <td><a href='<%#Eval("URL1")%>'>Link1</a></td>  <td style="text-align:center">   <%#Eval("AvgRJ1")%></td> </tr>
<tr>    <td style="width:40px">URL2</td>    <td><a href='<%#Eval("URL2")%>'>Link2</a></td>  <td style="text-align:center">   <%#Eval("AvgRJ2")%></td>  </tr>
<tr>    <td style="width:40px">URL3</td>    <td><a href='<%#Eval("URL3")%>'>Link3</a></td>  <td style="text-align:center">   <%#Eval("AvgRJ3")%></td>  </tr>
<tr>    <td style="width:40px">URL4</td>    <td><a href='<%#Eval("URL4")%>'>Link4</a></td>  <td style="text-align:center">   <%#Eval("AvgRJ4")%></td>  </tr>
<tr>    <td style="width:40px">URL5</td>    <td><a href='<%#Eval("URL5")%>'>Link5</a></td>  <td style="text-align:center">   <%#Eval("AvgRJ5")%></td>  </tr>
<tr>    <td style="width:40px">URL6</td>    <td><a href='<%#Eval("URL6")%>'>Link6</a></td>  <td style="text-align:center">   <%#Eval("AvgRJ6")%></td>  </tr>
<tr>    <td style="width:40px">URL7</td>    <td><a href='<%#Eval("URL7")%>'>Link7</a></td>  <td style="text-align:center">   <%#Eval("AvgRJ7")%></td>  </tr>
<tr>    <td style="width:40px">URL8</td>    <td><a href='<%#Eval("URL8")%>'>Link8</a></td>  <td style="text-align:center">   <%#Eval("AvgRJ8")%></td>  </tr>
<tr>    <td style="width:40px">URL9</td>    <td><a href='<%#Eval("URL9")%>'>Link9</a></td>  <td style="text-align:center">   <%#Eval("AvgRJ9")%></td>  </tr>
<tr>    <td style="width:40px">URL10</td>    <td><a href='<%#Eval("URL10")%>'>Link10</a></td> <td style="text-align:center">   <%#Eval("AvgRJ10")%></td>   </tr>
<tr>    <td >nDCG: </td>   <td> </td> <td><%#Eval("nDCG")%></td>    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
```

Why are the records not appearing horizontally? What is to be rectified?

Current layout the way it is appearing:

[image]

Required layout:

[image]

Comment: Edit your question to with screenshots to show how it is rendering currently, and how you want it to be.

Comment: @p.campbell: Added screenshots.

Comment: What do you get when you change <ItemTemplate> to <ItemTemplate><table> and </ItemTemplate> to </table></ItemTemplate>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the elements display in some sort of table but you don't have the `<table>` at the beginning of the ItemTemplate, and a closing tag `</table>` at the end of the ItemTemplate.